# Запуск кода python vim в отдельном буфере

Tags: python, vim, редактор

у меня есть конфигурация vim, скриншот показывает, как я запускаю python скрипт.

[image: плагин nvim]

Задача - сделать так, чтобы при запуске создавалось новое окно (как на скриншоте, только уже, примерно, четверть экрана и опция изменить расположение, чтобы запущенный скрипт был ниже относительно кода), где и будет запущен скрипт (обязательно с поддержкой input()) и фокус, чтобы был на этом окне с запущенным скриптом, чтобы я мог легко закрыть его.
Было бы прям круто, если показывалось название файла при запуске и время выполнения скрипта. Огромная благодарность всем заранее.

[image: Желаемый резултат]

Comment: `:ter` пробовали?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, но именно полный код мне трудно написать, я сбиваюсь, я понимаю, что тут нужна даже большая функцию серее всего, где прописаны действия последовательно, только все команды я не знаю, как - то трудно документацию гуглить, все по форумам нахожу

Comment: `:exec 'bo term ++rows=10 python %'`. выход по `:q` или `Ctrl-w c`. Если хочется автоматически закрывать после выполнения, то `:exec 'bo term ++close ++rows=10 python %'`